# Asp.Net Mvc 4 Validation Mechanism

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, modelbinders, business-rules

What is the best mechanism for validation in Asp.Net Mvc 4,

I mean validating at property level (Required, Length, etc) and Business Level (validating against business rules),

Is it a bad idea to choose ModelBinder (implementing some custom ModelBinder for some custom type)  for validating a model at business level?